# Unable to remove or re-attach FileStream FileGroup to a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream

Background: I had a working SQL Server Database created in SQL 2010, with 2 different FileStream/FileGroups, working fine.  I detached the database, moved it to another desktop with SQL 2016 (on Win 10 Pro), and manually copied the 2 Filestream folders (called ImageFS and **DocFS**).  I simply re-attached the mdf database and didn't pay attention to the Filestream functions because it wasn't being used.  Months later I noticed that one FileGroup/Fileshare (ImageFG/ImageFS) works fine, and the other one (**DocFG/DocFS**) doesn't.  In more detail, this is what I get

```
SELECT DocFileID, ModifiedDate FROM DocFile
-- WORKS FINE

SELECT DocFileID, ModifiedDate, Doc FROM DocFile
--Returns this error:
-- A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
```

So, Doc is the filestream field in this table.   I tried to remove the field and add it again, but SSMS won't let me:

```
ALTER TABLE DocFile DROP COLUMN Doc
--Returns this error:
-- The FILESTREAM filegroup '**DocFG**' has no files assigned to it. FILESTREAM data cannot be populated on this filegroup until a file is added.
-- Huh?  there are already files in this Windows folder
```

I also tried to shrink the DocFG filegroup to try to delete it but I get this error.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('DocFG', EMPTYFILE)
--Returns this error:
--Could not locate file 'DocFG' for database 'MyDB' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped.
```

I have tried to detach and reattach the database, using this code, but it doesn't make a difference:

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDB]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MyDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf' , SIZE = 71040KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
 FILEGROUP [ImageFG] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
( NAME = N'ImageFS', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\ImageFS' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED), 
 FILEGROUP [DocFG] CONTAINS FILESTREAM DEFAULT
( NAME = N'DocFS', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\DocFS' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
 LOG ON ( NAME = N'MyDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 43264KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
FOR ATTACH
```

This ataches fine, but DocFS/DocFG still doesn't work.   I also tried to use SSMS to manually "REMOVE" DocFG, but I get an error as well:

[SSMS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL2iQ.png)

[SSMS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg9ws.png)

Any thoughts about where to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was an oddball situation.  Somehow the DocFS (files tab of Database properties) and DocFG (filegroups tab of Database properties) were not in sync (for lack of a better term).  If you tried to re-create the DocFS based on DocFG, SSMS wouldn't let you.  The reason being that the original corresponding Windows directory was already there, and SSMS was trying to recreate one there.

**Solution** (for me, at least):

1. Rename the windows directory ("...\DocFS" in my case), to something temporary, such as "..\DocFS_Temp\")
2. go back and re-create the DocFS "file" in the files tab of Database Properties, being sure to select the corresponding FileGroup (e.g. DocFG).  This will then create a new "...\DocFS" Windows directory
3. Delete this newly created "...\DocFS" Windows directory
4. Rename the temp directory back to "...\DocFS"

Other housekeeping things I did (which may or may not have helped) ...I toggled the DB offline, and then back online.  I also had to toggle the auto-growth from unlimited to 10% and back to shake off a "directory is full" error.

I hope this helps someone else.